# Why font family doesn't working on device OPPO and OnePlus version 12 in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iXYH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPADe.png)

This is my config font.

Comment: Please share some code and some more details about your problem, perhaps add some images to illustrate it too, that would help people understand the issue :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Now I found the solution, I try to re-config font family again it work for me.